# How can I filter a MySQL result by the amount of words in a column?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to filter the result of a MySQL query by the number of words contained within a table column.

For example, I have 10 testimonials with the columns id, name, url, testimonial and five of those rows have a testimonial column with more than 100 words in to make up the testimonial.

How can I use a query to only return the rows which have less than a 100 words in that testimonial column?

Thanks,

Comment: @Shrapnel: A series of one or more characters with a space on either or both sides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I'm suggesting the way they've done it is massively great, but ...

http://www.mwasif.com/2008/12/count-number-of-words-in-a-mysql-column/

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(field) - LENGTH(REPLACE(field, ' ', '')) + 1 < 100
```

It actually counts the spaces ... but that might be close enough for you.

Comment: @jimy It is kind of ... as I said, it counts the spaces, but the number of words is actually 1 greater, assuming proper input.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't really have any "word" counting functions, but you could get a rough estimate by counting the number of spaces in a text field. Of course, there's no "how many characters 'x' are there in a string function), so you have to go at it in a roundabout fashion:

```
SELECT  LENGTH(textfield) - LENGTH(REPLACE(textfield, ' ', '') AS words
FROM ...
HAVING words < 100
```

Basically, get the length of the text field, then subtract the length of the same textfield with the spaces removed, giving you the number of spaces.

Comment: The length of the text minus the length of the text without spaces should, in theory, return the number of words minus 1 ... so I think +1 for you is oddly relevant :)